# Apply url validation regex on comma separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

Am trying to use the below regex for url validation.

```
/^((((.*):\/\/)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*';\/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!';\/?:,][[:blank:]])?$/i.test( value );
```

It works as expected when I provide a single URL. My input would consist of multiple URLs, which are comma separated and I would like to apply the above regex against all the individual URLs in the comma separated list. I would also like to prevent certain strings being used in the URL ( eg "name", "city" etc)

for example

- http://localhost:8080 is valid, accepted by above regex
- https://something.com is valid, accepted by above regex
- http://localhost:8080,something.com,something2.com is invalid, accepted by above regex
- http://name.com is invalid
- http://city.com is invalid

What changes do I need to make to my regex to achieve the above results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex works for single urls, you can make it work with lists using a combination of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Below my solution:

```
const isClean = str => ["name", "city"].every(word => !str.includes(word));
const isValid = input =>
  input
    .split(",")
    .every(
      value =>
        /^((((.*):\/\/)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*';/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!';/?:,][[:blank:]])?$/i.test(
          value
        ) && isClean(value)
    );

console.log(isValid("http://localhost:8080")); // true
console.log(isValid("https://something.com")); // true
console.log(isValid("http://localhost:8080,something.com,something2.com")); // false
console.log(isValid("http://localhost:8080,http://something.com,http://something2.com")); // true
console.log(isValid("http://name.com")); // false
console.log(isValid("http://city.com")); // false
```

[Run on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wjrp5xkql?fontsize=14)